# pandas.to_sql is writing zeros instead of the integer/float values

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have been trying to write a DataFrame to a MySQL database but pandas.to_sql is writing "0" in place of the numeric values.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import sqlalchemy from sqlalchemy.types import Float, Integer, DateTime, String

df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\file1.csv', chunksize = 100, index = False) 

df.to_sql('database_table', db_conn, index=False, chunksize=100, 
dtype={"date": DateTime, "code": String, "int_value": Integer,
"float_value": Float, "snapshot_dt": DateTime} , if_exists = 'append' )

df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\file2.csv', index=False, chunksize=100)
```

Both file1.csv and file2.csv were identical and the non-numeric values were as expected.  However, regardless of what the values of int_value and float_value were, 0 was what was stored in the database.

**[updated with df.dtypes, file1.csv, and file2.csv]**

**df.dtypes**

date           datetime64[ns]

code                   object

int_value               int64

float_value           float64

snapshot_dt    datetime64[ns]

dtype:object

**In MySQL**,

int_value is bigint(20)

float_value is double

I have tried writing to CSV and re-reading it back into a DataFrame, and everything else I can find on line - but I could not solve this problem.

The df.to_sql were working earlier but for some inexplicable reason, it started to misbehave.

What is possibly wrong?

Additional info:

Note: The blank lines are not present in the actual csv file.  They were added for readability in this post.

**file1.csv**

date,code,int_value,float_value,snapshot_dt

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,ABC,210,1.0,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,DEF,365,0.9605,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,GHI,393,1.0,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,JKL,377,0.8808,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,MNO,337,0.8686,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,PQR,256,1.0,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,STU,105,0.9722,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,VWX,227,0.9913,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,YZA,251,0.8423,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

**file2.csv**

date,code,int_value,float_value,snapshot_dt

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,ABC,210,1.0,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,DEF,365,0.9605,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,GHI,393,1.0,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,JKL,377,0.8808,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,MNO,337,0.8686,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,PQR,256,1.0,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,STU,105,0.9722,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,VWZ,227,0.9913,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

2019-12-21 00:00:00.000000,YZA,251,0.8423,2019-12-21 09:00:03.953165

Comment: is possible you can to add a example file csv ?

Comment: I have edited the post to include the file1.csv and file2.csv.  They are identical - not surprisingly since they came from the same DataFrame. I included both to make sure that it was not changed in the process of writing to_sql.

Comment: An update.  Without any changes, the DataFrame.to_csv now writes the correct values to the database.  I cannot explain this.